# Putting form controls in a navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Playing with Bootstrap 2.0, I could not put `form controls` in a `navbar` nicely. The [obvious guess](http://jsfiddle.net/7J7cz/) puts the search box too high.

How can I fix my fiddle?

Comment: Well if you wrap it up like so, its not as close to the top, however the bar becomes longer? http://jsfiddle.net/7J7cz/13/ Is that closer to what you want?

Comment: Hum. On my screen (Google Chrome for Mac) the search button appears over two-lines...

Comment: I can reproduce the error here on Chrome for Windows. Firefox shows it on one line only. Let me see if I can fix it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

if you place this in the .nav .container:

```
<form class="navbar-search pull-left">
  <input type="text" class="search-query" placeholder="Search">
</form>
```

You get a pretty search box: http://jsfiddle.net/p4eAN/1/

If you want to align the search bar on the right side change the 'pull-left' class to 'pull-right'

-update-
Combine the  with the input tags and add a tiny bit of css: http://jsfiddle.net/7J7cz/56/

```
.navbar-search .input-prepend {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

-update2-
Added a float:right to the input, this fixes Chrome, Firefox was already working and still works: http://jsfiddle.net/7J7cz/57/

Comment: I want to use *form controls*, not `navbar-search`.

Comment: You can still use the <form> tag with the related classes like so: http://jsfiddle.net/7J7cz/56/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7J7cz/57/  Added a float:right to the input, this fixes Chrome, Firefox was already working and still works.

Comment: I had to add a float:left; to the span's style to get it to work in Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Check this Out

```
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <form class="navbar-form form-inline">
                        <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" style="margin-left: 5px;" class="input-medium">
                          <option selected>Buy</option>
                          <option>Rent</option>
                        </select>

                        <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" required=""  placeholder = "Enter Location">

                        <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="span3">
                          <option selected>Property Type</option>
                          <option>Option two</option>
                        </select>

                        <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="input-small">
                          <option selected>Bedroom</option>
                          <option>Option two</option>
                        </select>

                        <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="input-small">
                          <option>Bathroom</option>
                          <option>Option two</option>
                        </select> 

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Search</button>
                        <a href="#" class="adv-search" data-id="<?php echo $fetch['stu_id']; ?>" title="Advance Search"><button class="btn" type="button" style="margin-left:10px;" ><i class="icon-th-list"></i></button></a>
                    </form>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.navbar -->
```

Answer (score 0):

the active class to the li element has a gap at the bottom
 Item 1